# having trouble with indenting in an enumerate environment

Tags: spacing, enumerate

This is my first time using tex to format an assignment, and I am having immense trouble making this work.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
\onehalfspace

\begin{enumerate}
  \item The first item\\
    \hspace{2cm} indented under first item\\
      \hspace{4cm} indented even more under first item
  \item The second item\\
    \hspace{2cm} indented under second item\\
      \hspace{4cm} indented even more under second item
  \item The third item\\
    \hspace{2cm} indented under third item\\
      \hspace{4cm} indented even more under third item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

That is what I have so far, but it won't seem to work. \hspace will not indent no matter what I do. I need indenting under the items because I am answering proof questions where I need this type of formatting.

Comment: Maybe onehalfspace is an environment:
`\begin{onehalfspace}`
`...`
`\end{onehalfspace}`.
The global option `sans` is not used.
Try `\hspace*{2cm}` etc.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto - The `setspace` package provides both a macro called `\onehalfspace` and an environment called `onehalfspace`.

Comment: @Mico: I could not find `\onehalfspace` in version `6.7a`.
But I found `\onehalfspacing`.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto - Sorry for being a bit elliptic. When LaTeX sets up the environment `onehalfspace`, it does so by defining (implicitly) the macros `\onehalfspace` and `\endonehalfspace`. Of course, `\onehalfspacing` works too.

Comment: @Mico - Thanks. I know that. Then the source needs `\endonehalfspace`.
I think it is better not to use such implicit cs's, if
they are not inevitably necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\hspace` instruction won't work in your case because there's nothing "there" yet at the start of the horizontal-mode material. You should use `\hspace*` instead of `\hspace`.